# Memory isolation autochecker

Tags: scoping, memory

I'm working on a project in which I'm putting everything in modules to make sure I can run multiple instances without them interfering with each other, however I'd like to have it automatically let me know if there are any variables that aren't defined as local to a module.

e.g.

```
DynamicModule[
{a,b,c}
a=5;
b=6;
c=7;
d=8
//Some more code here
]
```

What code could I put in the "Some more code here" section or after the module that would let me know that
`d`
is not defined as being local?

Comment: You can put everything in packages having own namespaces.

Comment: Syntax colouring can be very helpful. Restart the kernel, issue all necessary function definitions and global variable assignments, then skim through the code: black is defined, blue is undefined and green/teal is local. There should be nothing that looks blue. `d` in your sample code would be blue. Note that the sample code is wrong: you are missing a comma and `//` does not start a comment. Fix these and try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use packages as I need to deploy this out to the consumers as a single file.

Comment: Syntax coloring helps, but with the size of this file I would rather have a way to have it print out anything that is not localized so I can go easily find it and localize it rather than scrolling and hunting to check everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction

It is an interesting problem if one tries to solve it using Mathematica's meta-programming capabilities. One idea which I have tried to implement is to process `Module` and `DynamicModule` code, lexically, to identify assignments to variables which have not been localized.

What I ended up doing was to generate extra code that would issue a message for such assignments, but otherwise keep them unchanged - this seems to be the least intrusive method. The code below is however only a proof of concept, and while I believe it covers a large portion of cases, it does not cover all possible ways to mutate a variable (in particular, it does not cover `UpValues` and only partially
covers `SubValues`).

The code I ended up with is rather long, to the extent that I was hesitating to provide it all here instead of putting it elsewhere and linking, but decided to still provide it here to keep the answer self-contained.

### Illustration

In what follows, I assume that that code has been already executed first.

#### Some examples to try

First, enable the "debug" regime (by default it will only track symbols from `` "Global`" `` context):

```
setBoundVarChecks[]
```

Then, for example, try

```
Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, 
  c = 3;
  a + b + c
]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[156]:= customSet::unbound: Assignment c = 3 to an unbound symbol c. The bound symbols at this level are {a$9690,b$9690}
> ```

```
(* 6 *)
```

whereas

```
Module[{c},
  Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, 
    c = 3;
    a + b + c
  ]
]

(* 6 *)
```

runs without warnings.

You can try many other combinations, with both `Module` and `DynamicModule`, and different types of assignments. Some examples:

```
Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, c := 3; a + b + c]

Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, c++; a + b + c]

d = {}; Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, AppendTo[d, 3];a + b + c]

Module[{a = 1, b = 2}, e[1][3] = 15; a + b + c]

DynamicModule[{a, b, c}, a = 5; b = 6; c = 7; d = 8]

DynamicModule[{a, b, c},
  a = 5;
  b = 6;
  c = 7;
  Button["Press", d = 8; Print[d]]
]
```

where in the last example, the warning message will be printed to the `Messages` window when the button is pressed.

When done with this "debug" regime, call

```
unsetBoundVarChecks[]
```

#### How it works

I will start with a simple example to illustrate the idea. Say we start with the following code:

```
Module[{a = 1}, b = 2; a + b]
```

where variable `b` is non-local to the `Module`. There are two options then: it is either local to some surrounding `Module`, or it is global.

Assuming for the moment the first scenario, we process the above code as:

```
processModuleCore[Module[{a = 1}, b = 2; a + b]]

(*
 Hold[Module[
   {a=1},
   Message[customSet::unbound,"b = 2", HoldForm[b], HoldForm[{a}]];
   $dummy;
   b=2;
   a+b
 ]]
*)
```

Let me explain in some detail how `processModuleCore` works.

The following will detect inner assignments and replace them all with some custom assignment operator `customSet`:

```
rc = replaceAssignments[][Hold @ Module[{a = 1}, b = 2; a + b]]

(* Hold[customHold[Module @@ Hold[{a = 1}, customSet[b, 2, {a}, Set]; a + b]]] *)
```

(note that we wrapper the `Module` in `Hold`). The following will process the previous result, and generate the new assignment code:

```
generateAssignmentCode @ rc

(*

Hold[customHold[
  Module @@ Hold[
    {a=1},
    customHold[Message[customSet::unbound,b = 2,b,{a}];($dummy;b=2)];a+b
  ]
]]

*)
```

Some postprocessing produces the final new code for `Module`:

```
flattenCE @removeCustomHold @ generateAssignmentCode @ rc 

(*
 Hold[Module[
   {a=1},
   Message[customSet::unbound,"b = 2", HoldForm[b], HoldForm[{a}]];
   $dummy;
   b=2;
   a+b
 ]]
*)
```

The new lines that have been generated are a line with a warning message, and the `$dummy` symbol (which will only be needed to keep track that we have processed this `Module`).

Assuming that the variable `b` has been localized in some outer `Module`, we would do instead

```
flattenCE @removeCustomHold @ generateAssignmentCode @ replaceAssignments[b][
  Hold @ Module[{a = 1}, b = 2; a + b]
]

(* Hold[Module[{a = 1}, $dummy; b = 2; a + b]] *)
```

where `b` has now been passed into `replaceAssignments`, and the end result of that has been that the message is no longer present in the generated code.

Now we may want to attach a global rule which would replace all `Module`-s and `DynamicModule`- s in code by the result of `processCodeCore` called on them. This is admittedly a dangerous step, since the only way to do this is to add `DownValues` to `Module` and `DynamicModule`. So I would only suggest to do this for testing, and while I have tested on a few less trivial examples, I can't guarantee that it would always work well. The top-level functions which automate this step are

```
setBoundVarChecks[contextsToCheck: {___String} | Automatic : Automatic]
unsetBoundVarChecks[]
```

where the first one adds relevant definitions to `Module` and `DynamicModule`, and the second one removes them.

### Summary

I have outlined one approach to the problem, which is based on generation of some additional code in the form of warning messages, at run-time during code execution. **Note that it overloads `Module` and `DynamicModule` globally, and therefore is dangerous and only at best suited for debugging purposes**. Note also that the code as written does not cover all ways in which a variable can be mutated, so this is rather a proof of concept, not a complete robust solution.

That said, it may still be useful.

### Code

```
$includedContexts = {"Global`"}
$excludedContexts = {"System`"}

ClearAll[customSet, $CustomNone]
SetAttributes[customSet, HoldAll]
customSet::unbound = "Assignment `1` to an unbound symbol `2`. The bound symbols at this level are `3`";

customSet[set_, lhs_, $CustomNone] := ($dummy;set[lhs])

customSet[set_, lhs_, rhs_] := ($dummy;set[lhs, rhs])

customSet[lhs: sym_Symbol | sym_Symbol[___] | sym_Symbol[___][___], rhs_, {___, sym_, ___}, set_] := 
customSet[set, lhs, rhs]

customSet[
    lhs: sym_Symbol | sym_Symbol[___] | sym_Symbol[___][___], rhs_, _, set_
] /; !MemberQ[Complement[$includedContexts, $excludedContexts], Context[sym]] :=    
  customSet[set, lhs, rhs]

customSet[lhs: sym_Symbol | sym_Symbol[___] | sym_Symbol[___][___], rhs_, vars_, set_] := 
  With[{str = ToString @ ReplaceAll[
          HoldForm[customSet[set, lhs, rhs]] /. DownValues[customSet],
          HoldPattern[$dummy; c_] :> c
       ]},
        (
            Message[customSet::unbound, str, HoldForm[sym], HoldForm[vars]]; 
            customSet[set, lhs, rhs]
        ) /; True
  ]

customSet[lhs_, rhs_, _, set_] := customSet[set, lhs, rhs]


ClearAll[constructNeedsProcessingQ];
SetAttributes[constructNeedsProcessingQ, HoldAll];
constructNeedsProcessingQ[construct_] :=FreeQ[Unevaluated @ construct, $dummy]

ClearAll[customHold];
SetAttributes[customHold, HoldAll]


ClearAll[getHeldLocalizedVariables]
SetAttributes[getHeldLocalizedVariables, HoldAll]
getHeldLocalizedVariables[
  expr: (head: Module | DynamicModule | With | Block)[{vars___}, __], 
  inheritedVars___Symbol
] :=
Replace[
    Replace[
        head, 
        {
            Module | DynamicModule :> Hold[inheritedVars, vars],
            With | Block :> Hold[vars]
        }
    ],
    HoldPattern[var_ = _] :> var,
    {1}
]

ClearAll[setReplaceInModuleScope]
SetAttributes[setReplaceInModuleScope, HoldAll];
setReplaceInModuleScope[
  expr: (head: Module | DynamicModule | With | Block) [{vars___}, body_, rest___], 
  topVars___
] :=
Replace[
    Apply[
      replaceAssignments, 
      getHeldLocalizedVariables[expr, topVars]
    ][Hold[body]],
    Hold[newbody_] :> customHold[head @@ Hold[{vars}, newbody, rest]]
]

ClearAll[generateAssignmentCode]
SetAttributes[generateAssignmentCode, HoldAll]
generateAssignmentCode[set_customSet] := 
  customHold[set] //. DownValues[customSet]

generateAssignmentCode[expr_] := 
  ReplaceRepeated[
    expr, 
    assignment_customSet :> RuleCondition @ generateAssignmentCode[assignment]
  ]

ClearAll[replaceAssignments];
SetAttributes[replaceAssignments, HoldAll];
replaceAssignments[vars___] := ReplaceAll[
  {
    HoldPattern[m:_DynamicModule|_Module|_With|_Block] :> 
        RuleCondition @ setReplaceInModuleScope[m, vars]
    ,
    HoldPattern[(set: Set | SetDelayed | AppendTo | PrependTo | AddTo | AssociateTo)[lhs_, rhs_]] :> 
        customSet[lhs, rhs, {vars}, set]
    ,
    HoldPattern[(set: Increment | PreIncrement | Decrement | PreDecrement)[val_]] :>
        customSet[val, $CustomNone, {vars}, set]
    ,
    c : HoldPattern[customSet[_, _, {___, vars}, _]] :> c
    , 
    HoldPattern[customSet[lhs_, rhs_, {prev__}, set_]] :> customSet[lhs, rhs, {prev, vars}, set]
  }
]

ClearAll[removeCustomHold];
removeCustomHold = ReplaceRepeated[
  {
    customHold[Apply[head_, Hold[parts___]]] :> head[parts],
    customHold[x___] :> x
  }
]

ClearAll[flattenCE]
flattenCE = 
  ReplaceRepeated[
    HoldPattern[CompoundExpression[left___, CompoundExpression[middle___], right___]] :> 
        CompoundExpression[left, middle, right]
  ]

ClearAll[processModuleCore];
SetAttributes[processModuleCore, HoldAll]
processModuleCore[d:_Module | _DynamicModule] := 
  Composition[
    flattenCE,
    removeCustomHold,
    generateAssignmentCode
  ] @ Hold[Evaluate[setReplaceInModuleScope[d]]]


ClearAll[processModule];
SetAttributes[processModule, HoldFirst];
processModule[d_, context_String] := processModule[d, {context}]

processModule[d:_Module | _DynamicModule, contextsToCheck: {___String} | Automatic : Automatic] := 
  Replace[
    {processModuleCore[d], contextsToCheck},
    {
        {processed_, Automatic} :> processed,
        {Hold[code_], c_} :> Hold[Block[{$includedContexts = c}, code]]
    }
  ]

ClearAll[alterProtectedDownValues]
alterProtectedDownValues[sym_, func_] :=
  (
    Unprotect[sym];
    DownValues[sym] = func[DownValues[sym]];
    Protect[sym]
  )

ClearAll[setModuleCheck, unsetModuleCheck, $inConstruct];
setModuleCheck[construct_Symbol, contextsToCheck: {___String} : Automatic] :=
(
    unsetModuleCheck[construct];
    alterProtectedDownValues[
      construct, 
      Prepend[
        d_construct?constructNeedsProcessingQ /; !TrueQ[$inConstruct] :> Block[
          {$inConstruct = True},
          ReleaseHold @ processModule[d, contextsToCheck]
        ]
      ]
    ]
)

unsetModuleCheck[construct_Symbol] := alterProtectedDownValues[
  construct,
  DeleteCases[def_ /; !FreeQ[def, $inConstruct]]
]


ClearAll[setBoundVarChecks, unsetBoundVarChecks]
setBoundVarChecks[contextsToCheck: {___String} | Automatic : Automatic] := 
  Scan[setModuleCheck, {Module, DynamicModule}]

unsetBoundVarChecks[] := Scan[unsetModuleCheck, {Module, DynamicModule}]
```

Comment: I'm afraid I am having an incredibly difficult time understanding this, but I greatly appreciate it. I think I may be able to make some use of this given enough time.

Comment: @Daniel Well, one can use this code also without deep understanding of the internals. If you execute is, then when you call `setBoundVarChecks[]`, this turns on the "debug" mode where all assignments to / mutations of non-localized variables inside `Module` or `DynamicModule` will issue a message. To return back to normal code execution regime, just call `unsetBoundVarChecks []`. That's basically it, on the "user" level.

Comment: Oh thanks! This is incredible, and so easy to use. It even works on my nested Dynamic Modules

Comment: @Daniel Glad you found it helpful. Thanks for the accept. Keep in mind the caveats I mentioned - there may be cases the current code will miss (probably not hard to account for them though - if you come across any, ping me here in comments and I will try to address them).

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a bit of a hack, based on `Module` assigning unique names to localized variables that contain “$” and a number:

```
DynamicModule[
  {a}, 
  Echo@ StringContainsQ[SymbolName[a], "$"];
  Echo@ StringContainsQ[SymbolName[d], "$"]
]
```

The above will return `True` for `a` that has been localized, but `False` for global variable `d`. The `Echo` is just for visualization here; you would probably use the Boolean output from `StringContainsQ` directly.

Of course, this relies on you avoiding `$` in your global variable names (probably a good idea regardless), and on `Module`‘s renaming behavior not changing in the future. Hence the reason why I think this is a bit of a hack.

Comment: This isn't really what I want, this is what I'm trying to avoid. I have so many variables that I don't want to have to go through and double check every single variable name to ensure that it has been localized. I'd like to have some script run that tells me if there are any variables defined at any point that are not localized.

Comment: @Daniel that may be very hard to do. You might be interested in e.g. `Names[“Global`*”]` but even there quite a few unexpected things will show up... perhaps more than point, *why* do you need to know? There might be alternative approaches...

Comment: @Daniel, you can try to look for a list of variables that does not have a $-sign in the name: `Complement[Names["Global`*"], Names["Global`*$*"]]`

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your work, you could take a snapshot of the variables in "Global`":

```
old = Names["Global`*"];
```

Later, when you want to check if there are no new global variables, you take another snapshot and calculate the complement:

```
new = Names["Global`*"];
Complement[new, old]
```

Comment: This is not correct. `Module[{a=0}, 1]` creates the symbol `a` in the Global context. It does not assign any value to it, but it creates the symbol.

Comment: Try:f[x_]= Module[{a}, x];
Names["Global`*"]; I can't see any "a"

Comment: That's because of the `;` after the `Names` call :-) You suppressed the output by accident.

Comment: It is so easy to fool oneself!

Comment: It looks like this will work for me after some modifications, thanks!

Comment: I am glad you found a solution despite some obstacles.